# How to use a image as a submit button, to submit itself to server?

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms, src

```
<form name="myform" action="app.py">
<div class="box">

<input type="image" id="image" src="http://mychickencoopplans.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/happy-chicken.jpg" >

</div>
</form>
```

I'm trying to create a picture that will send it's src to the server (app.py) when clicked? How would I accomplish this using HTML/javascript? Thanks.

Comment: How about giving the image input a name and setting the value to the same as the src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    <form name="myform" action="app.py">
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="hidSrc">
        <div class="box">
            <input type="image" id="image" onclick="document.getElementById('hidSrc').value = this.src;document.myform.submit();" src="http://mychickencoopplans.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/happy-chicken.jpg" >
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<form name="myform" action="app.py">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="hidimgSrc">
    <div class="box">
        <input type="image" id="image" onclick="document.getElementById('hidimgSrc').value = this.src;document.getElementById('myform').submit();" src="http://mychickencoopplans.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/happy-chicken.jpg" >
    </div>
</form>
```